# Calculating differences in a vector for specific elements

Tags: r

I want to calculate the differences between elements in a vector, using the function diff. But I only want to do this for the elements that take on a certain value.

Let's say I have a vector

```
v <- c(0,1,3,5,0,7,6,0,9,0,7,2)
```

and I only want the differences from the zeros (or any other value). So I would get the result
1,7,9,7.

I want to write something like:

```
diff(v for which v == 0)
```

But I dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use `diff` for elements with 0, we can select the elements which are next to 0 because any number subtracted by 0 is the same number.

```
v[which(v == 0) + 1]
#[1] 1 7 9 7
```

---

If there is any other number apart from 0 we want to use `diff` we can select the next number and subtract it with that number.

```
v[which(v == 0) + 1] - v[which(v == 0)]
#[1] 1 7 9 7
```

With 7

```
v[which(v == 7) + 1] - v[which(v == 7)]
#[1] -1 -5
```

---

If we want to use `diff` we can get the indices which are 0 and the number next to it, `split` it based on occurrence of 0 and calculate the difference using `diff`.

```
inds <- which(v == 0)
v1 <- v[sort(c(inds, inds + 1))]
sapply(split(v1, cumsum(v1 == 0)), diff)

#1 2 3 4 
#1 7 9 7
```

Comment: Okay, but if I wanted to this with any other value than 0?